# Does this PyList_New, PyList_SET_ITEM, Py_BuildValue combination leak?

Tags: python, c

```
PyObject *list_over_proposals = PyList_New(n_proposals);
for (size_t j = 0; j < n_proposals; j++) {
    PyList_SET_ITEM(list_over_proposals, j,
        Py_BuildValue("[i,i,i,i]", a, b, c, d));
}
```

This seg faults after a few hundred iterations, despite a, b, c, and d being typical integers (all between 1 and 500 or so), even during the last iteration just before the seg fault.

Misc info: Python 2.7.3, g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1

Comment: I don't find any evident flaw. What about using `PyList_SetItem` and check the return value?

Comment: I tried this. Returns 0 always, as expected. I further determined that the Py_BuildValue call is what's resulting in the seg fault. (And, up until the point of seg fault, it returns seemingly-correct memory addresses.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here might be that all of the Py* functionality, including the PyArray* functionality, is at-your-own-risk *unless* you properly modify your code to become a C extension module. (I was not doing this; I was just calling the functions through ctypes.)

A clear writeup on the subject is [here](http://dan.iel.fm/posts/python-c-extensions/). There is a little bit of boilerplate, but other than that, this method is pretty nice. No external dependencies (like Boost.Python), and it makes your Python code very clean, eliminating the need for specifying function signatures via ctypes.